# Why is this Markov chain's stationary distribution not (1/2, 0, 0, 1/2)?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I have the Markov chain

```
 1,  0,  0,  0
1/2, 0, 1/2, 0
 0, 1/2, 0, 1/2
 0,  0,  0,  1
```

I understand how to build the system with which I am supposed to find that stationary distribution. But my coursebook says that the answer is in fact (p, 0, 0, 1-p), without `p` being mentioned before and, intuitively, I believe that the answer should be (0.5, 0, 0, 0.5). Where are they getting this answer from?

Comment: Can you post the question from the book? I don't see a $p$ either.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Matrices [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5023/290196).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = [p;\ 0;\ 0;\ 1 - p]$ be a row vector. It is not hard to verify that for any $0 \leq p \leq 1$,
$$
x = xP
$$
where $P$ is the transition probability matrix.

---

Note that your Markov chain is not **recurrent** (or persistent). There is no way out from the first state and the fourth state. **Therefore, the chain does not possess a unique steady distribution.**

Comment: Why do we care that x=xP? Anyway, what you are saying is that p comes from the fact that we care about the initial state. If we end up being in A1 more often than A4 right form the start, the p will reflect that?

Comment: @Mackiavelli The stationary distributions are eigenvectors of $1$.

Comment: @Mackiavelli I actually meant that if you start at a different state, the probability of entering state $1$ and state $4$ will vary too. State $1$ and state $4$ serve as absorbing states in this example, i.e., once you enter these two states, you can not leave anymore.

Comment: @Mackiavelli: A stationary distribution for $P$ is any $x$ with $x=xP$ (and, since it is a distribution, sum $1$ and non-negative terms)